# JSON array to C# List

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How can I deserialize this simple JSON string to a list in C# ?

```
["on4ThnU7","n71YZYVKD","CVfSpM2W","10kQotV"]
```

such that,

```
List<string> myStrings = [the content of the JSON above]
```

I am using DataContractJsonSerializer found in System.Runtime.Serialization.Json, and don't need external library.

EDIT:
JavaScriptSerializer found in System.Web.Script.Serialization is also acceptable.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506542/deserializing-json-using-system-runtime-serialization-json

Comment: I saw that already. The JSON data structure is really different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this,

```
  string json = "[\"on4ThnU7\",\"n71YZYVKD\",\"CVfSpM2W\",\"10kQotV\"]";
  var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<String>>(json);
```

Comment: why does it has "\" though? unlike post above

Comment: Thats how you format json, otherwise compiler woll show an error!

Comment: got it! given that the json is provided plainly within the code. lesson learned on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string data to `bytes[]`, wrap it in a `MemoryStream`, and use `DataContractJsonSerializer` for deserialization:

```
string stringData = "[\"on4ThnU7\", \"n71YZYVKD\", \"CVfSpM2W\", \"10kQotV\"]";
string[] arrayData;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringData)))
{
    var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[]));
    arrayData = deserializer.ReadObject(ms) as string[];
}
if (arrayData == null) 
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong data");
else
{
    foreach (var item in arrayData) 
        Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Json.Net, make sure you import `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

and deserialize the json as below

```
string json = @"[""on4ThnU7"",""n71YZYVKD"",""CVfSpM2W"",""10kQotV""]";
List<string> myStrings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
foreach (string str in myStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Output

```
on4ThnU7
n71YZYVKD
CVfSpM2W
10kQotV
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4OLS2v

Comment: thanks ekad! Much like my answer above. I appreciate it lots. Hope you can be there again next time! :)

Comment: where is JsonConvert though? didn't see it under that namespace.

Comment: so that's what I was saying: I didn't want to use any of those external libs. don't want to deal with dependencies when application is deployed.
it MUST be a `System.something` namespace.

Comment: If that's the case, then [Sajeetharan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27242346/1905949) is what you're looking for. I'm just giving an alternative of using json.net.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

> using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

```
public List<string> MyJsonDeserializer(string filename)
{
    //get json data
    Stream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
    string jsonData = new StreamReader(fs).ReadToEnd();
    fs.Close(); 

    //deserialize json data to c# list
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return (List<string>)serializer.Deserialize(jsonData, typeof(List<string>));        
}
```

Comment: what is the difference to the answer i have posted above?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List stringList = serializer.Deserialize>(inpustJson);

Answer (score 0):

### Modern C#: `System.Text.Json`

Since .NET Core 3.1 .NET comes with the `System.Text.Json` namespace which allows JSON (De-)Serialization without using any library.

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

> The `System.Text.Json` namespace provides functionality for serializing to and deserializing from JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). The `System.Text.Json` library is included in the runtime for **.NET Core 3.1 and later versions**. For **other target frameworks**, install the **`System.Text.Json` NuGet package**. The package supports:

- .NET Standard 2.0 and later versions
- .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions
- .NET Core 2.0, 2.1, and 2.2

To deserialize you need to use an appropriate type of your choice that can hold multiple values like e.g `IEnumerable<string>`, `List<string>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<string>` etc. whatever is the datatype that fits your needs best.

> Using C# 11 and .NET 7 you can now use [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals), which makes declaring JSON in code much easier and more readable and you don't need to escape every `"`.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

var content = """
    [
      "on4ThnU7", 
      "n71YZYVKD", 
      "CVfSpM2W", 
      "10kQotV"
    ]
    """;
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IReadOnlyCollection<string>>(content);
foreach (var item in serialized)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Expected output:

```
on4ThnU7
n71YZYVKD
CVfSpM2W
10kQotV
```

For how to migrate from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json` see the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0).